# mac os x server running mysql servererror - services wont start

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, mysql5.1

Mysql server running on Mac OS X
the my.cnf file had max_connections = 10000000

client got the error 'max connections reached'
restarted server, now it won't start the mysql services

bellow is an error when running mysqld_safe

i set the max_connections = 100, but the server will still not start the SQL services

```
EWELS:bin administrator$ sudo mysqld_safe
110419 14:04:15 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--512'
Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/mysql
STOPPING server from pid file /var/mysql/JEWELS.LOCAL.pid
110419 14:04:15  mysqld ended
```

any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem fixed - jumped the gun with question again

max_connections was 1000000

whenever i changed this it didnt work

int he end i renamed the my.cnf file to my.cnf.back

ran sudo mysqld_safe and it created a new config file and restored all defaults - services started as expected.

thanks anyway